# How to use a different locale as default locale for languages?

Tags: android, android-resources

Android currently uses Spain as the default locale for Español, but say I want to have another locale, such as Mexico, for the default locale to be resolved to for Español, is there a way I can do it?

What I mean is, say someone have strings for Español (Spain) and strings for Español (Mexico), they'd put the Spain ones in the folder values-es and the Mexico ones in values-es-rMX, so other locales will default to values-es which is Spain strings. I want to have it such that other locales will default to the Mexico ones, and have Spain strings resolve to Español (Spain).

I've tried using Español (Mexico) as values-es and Español (Spain) in values-es-rES, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

file -- _App.java

```
public class App extends Application {
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    LocaleUtils.setLocale(new Locale("iw"));
    LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this, 
getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this, newConfig);
}
}
```

onfile -- _BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public BaseActivity() {
    LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this);
}
}
```

on file LocaleUtils.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleUtils {

public static final String LAN_SPANISH      = "es";
public static final String LAN_PORTUGUESE   = "pt";
public static final String LAN_ENGLISH      = "en";

private static Locale sLocale;

public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    sLocale = locale;
    if(sLocale != null) {
        Locale.setDefault(sLocale);
    }
}

public static void updateConfig(ContextThemeWrapper wrapper) {
    if(sLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setLocale(sLocale);
        wrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}

public static void updateConfig(Application app, Configuration configuration) {
    if(sLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 
Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        //Wrapping the configuration to avoid Activity endless loop
        Configuration config = new Configuration(configuration);
        config.locale = sLocale;
        Resources res = app.getBaseContext().getResources();
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
}
```

You may refer to this link for better understand and on which events you should call your codes on your app , [click here fore more details](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758)

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using Español (Mexico) as values-es and Español (Spain) in values-es-rES, but that doesn't work.

I'm not sure what you tried that makes you say this, but generally that *should* work.

The resources framework in general will always try to choose the most-specific rules to match, but will fall back to more and more generic rules if it can't find a match. There's another wrinkle for locales on API 24+ ([read more here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support)), but the general pattern still holds.

The languages and dialects you choose to be "default" are entirely up to you; nothing says you have to put english text in your `res/values/strings.xml` file. You can put whatever language you want there, as long as you're happy with anyone who doesn't get a more-specific match seeing these default strings.

So, you could design your resources directory like this:

```
res/
    values/
        strings.xml (English text here)
    values-es/
        strings.xml (Mexican Spanish text here)
    values-es-rES/
        strings.xml (Spain Spanish text here)
```

This would mean:

- Anyone with their phone set to exactly Spain Spanish would see Spain Spanish text
- Anyone with their phone set to any other dialect of Spanish would see Mexican Spanish text
- Anyone with their phone set to any other language at all would see English text